# merging rows in postgres with matching fields

Tags: postgresql

I have a table format that appears in this type of format:

```
email               |   interest  |     major   | employed  |inserttime
jake@example.com    |   soccer    |             | true      |  12:00
jake@example.com    |             |     CS      | true      |  12:01
```

Essentially, this is a survey application and users sometimes hit the back button to add new fields. I later changed the `INSERT` logic to `UPSERT` so it just updated the row `where email=currentUsersEmail` , however for the data inserted prior to this code change there are many duplicate entries for single users. i have tried some group by's with no luck, as it continually says the

> ID column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function.

Certainly there will be edge cases where there may be clashing data, in this case maybe user entered `true` for the employed column and then in the second he/she could have enter `false`. For now I am not going to take this into account yet.

I simply want to merge or flatten these values into a single row, in this case it would look like:

```
email               |   interest  |     major   | employed  |inserttime
jake@example.com    |   soccer    |     CS      | true      |  12:01
```

I am guessing I would take the most recent inserttime. I have been writing the web application in scala/play, but for this task i think probably using a language like python might be easier if i cannot do it directly through psql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` and flatten using `MAX()`:

```
SELECT email, MAX(interest) AS interest,
       MAX(major) AS major,MAX(employed) AS employed,
       MAX(inserttime) AS inserttime
FROM your_table
GROUP BY email
```

Comment: wow thank you . i tried using MAX but wasn't sure how to use it exactly. will mark as correct in about 10 minutes when SO allows me to.

Comment: @kinghenry14 Great to hear I can help :)